# Logic consistency

Tags: logic, model-theory

I've reading about consistent theories and I had a question. As union of arbitrary functions does not necessarily give a function, I wonder if union of consistent theories is consistent. My intuition says that it is not true at all, so, I tried to construct a counterexample but before it, look at the following reasoning:

Take the sentence $\varphi: \forall x \forall y(xRy→yRx)$. I realized that $\langle \mathbb{N}, = \rangle$ is a model for $\Sigma=\{ \varphi \}$, meaning that $\Sigma$ is satisfiable and then, $\Sigma$ must be consistent.

Is this reasoning true at all? ¡Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let us have a language whose only extralogical symbols are constants $0$ and $1$. Let $T_1$ be the theory with sole axiom $0=1$, and $T_2$ be the theory with sole axiom $0\neq 1$.

Comment: Yes, that reasoning is true. And I presume where you're going is that $(\mathbb N, <)$ is a model of the negation of that sentence, so the negation is also consistent in isolation. Yes, the idea is that two theories can be consistent individually, but not consistent with each other. One prominent example is incompleteness: if a sentence $\phi$ can't be proven or refuted from $T,$ then $T\cup\{\phi\}$ and $T\cup\{\lnot\phi\}$ are both consistent, but their union obviously isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys! @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, I was trying to create that counterexample :)